# mysqldump unknown variable sql_mode error

Tags: mysql

**Help requested on 'mysqldump' error**

I'm in the hell figuring out why following error happens. So, please, anybody help me. My writing: A, B, C, D
s
A. Here is my.ini file

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir = C:\mysql-5.6.27
datadir = C:\mysql-5.6.27\data
port = 3306

max_allowed_packet=16M
character-set-client-handshake = false

init_connect="SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci"
init_connect="SET NAMES utf8"
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

skip-character-set-client-handshake
default-character-set=utf8

#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqldump]
#sql_mode=NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
```

========================== end of ini file

B. I executed the following command ==>

```
C:\mysql-5.6.27\bin> mysqldump -uroot -p --databases parkinglot > prugio.sql
```

C. Here is the response on my mysqldump

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'sql+mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
```

D. For your reference, I upgraded mysql version from 5.6.24 to 5.6.27.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I just found answer myself. I had my.ini in two plases. one in C drive and the other one in D drive. That caused the confusion. As soon as I renamed one of the my.ini, the problem didn't happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer myself. I had my.ini in two plases. one in C drive and the other one in D drive. That caused the confusion. As soon as I renamed one of the my.ini, the problem didn't happen.